# coding help for physical drum machines

Tags: encoding, computer-science

Me and some people are making and selling some physical drum machines, where if you press a button on a board, a related sound is played. Now I'm familiar with Microsoft Small basic and visual and html, however I'm not sure on programming the physical button to play an mp3 audio file, and set it so that you can choose a category of sounds too, thus If you press
Say a number on the machine, then the sounds played will be different. How would I go about doing this? I'm thinking of using a raspberry pi. Also if you could leave an email too, as I may need future help.

Comment: _'leave an email'_ - are you serious?

Comment: have you tried to make the code?

Comment: Randyka I have tried, but can only seem to manage with on screen buttons, not physicall buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out a Chumby Hacker board instead of a raspberry pi as they have audio inputs and inputs included.

This site will tell you all you need to know about the required code for the button.

https://learn.adafruit.com/playing-sounds-and-using-buttons-with-raspberry-pi/overview

While I hour this helps, please keep in mind that this site is for people who have already tried to solve their problem and failed.   I produced this answer with a Google search and 5 minutes of reading.